# Linked lists in C, how to fix expected identifier error?

Tags: c

I am new to C and I can't get this thing to compile properly, can you help me?

```
struct tagNode
{
    int v, f;

    struct tagNode *next;

    struct tagNode( int _v )
    {
        v = _v;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
```

expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘int’:
     struct tagNode( int _v )

Comment: It doesn't compile as C, because the code is C++.

Comment: If this is supposed to be C, then you can't put functions inside structure definitions - only declarations.

Comment: @StoryTeller And not even valid C++. Constructors can't have the `struct` or `class` keyword in their declaration.

Comment: @makc2099 Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘int’: struct tagNode( int _v )

this is because of the unexpected *struct* when you compile in **C++**

A valid version of your code in **C++** can be:

```
struct tagNode
{
    int v, f;

    tagNode *next;

    tagNode (int _v)
    {
        v = _v;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
```

but

- what about *f* ?
- the constructor can also be `tagNode(int _v) : v(_v), next(NULL) {}`
- and you have a pointer so I recommend you to look at the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

---

There is no constructor/methods in **C** so the equivalent of your code in **C** can be :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tagNode
{
  int v, f;
  struct tagNode * next;
};

struct tagNode * alloc(int _v)
{
  struct tagNode * r = malloc(sizeof(struct tagNode));

  r->v = _v;
  r->next = NULL;
  return r;
}
```